# Video transcoding using ffmpeg

Tags: python, performance, stream, video

I am transcoding video to different quality using ffmpeg using subprocess in Python. I want to make my transcoding faster. I tried multi-threading but it didn't help. Hardware acceleration is not possible as we are using an AWS EC2 t3.large instance at this time, which has 2 CPUs, 8GiB memory, and 30% baseline performance. Can you suggest something maybe regarding the ffmpeg command or update the code?

```
def transcode_video(video, quality, file_name):
try:
    quality_mapping = {
        "360p": "640x360",
        "480p": "854x480",
        "720p": "1280x720",
        "1080p": "1920x1080"
    }

    if quality not in quality_mapping:
        raise ValueError(f"Quality '{quality}' not supported")

    video_name, video_ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)

    # Construct output path with quality suffix
    output_path = f"{video_name}_{quality}{video_ext}"

    # Create FFmpeg object with streaming
    ffmpeg_command = [
        'ffmpeg',
        '-i', 'pipe:0',
        '-vf', f'scale={quality_mapping[quality]}',
        '-c:a', 'aac',
        '-c:v', 'libx264',
        '-preset', 'ultrafast',
        '-crf', '23',
        '-strict', 'experimental',
        output_path
    ]

    # Use subprocess.PIPE for stdin and stdout
    with subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) as process:
        # Write video content to stdin
        process.stdin.write(video.read())
        process.stdin.close()  # Close stdin to indicate the end of input

        # Wait for the process to finish
        process.wait()

    return output_path

except FileNotFoundError as e:
    # Clean up temporary file
    # if 'temp_file_path' in locals() and os.path.exists(temp_file_path):
    #     os.remove(temp_file_path)
    # Remove output file after returning
    if 'output_path' in locals() and os.path.exists(output_path):
        os.remove(output_path)

    raise e
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    if 'output_path' in locals() and os.path.exists(output_path):
        os.remove(output_path)

    raise e
except Exception as e:
    if 'output_path' in locals() and os.path.exists(output_path):
        os.remove(output_path)
    raise e
```

Comment: Encoding video is slow. You can make it faster by picking a cheaper codec or cheaper settings for your current codec. But that invariably leads to larger files (ie less compression) because speed and amount of compression tend to be inversely related.

Answer (score 4):

Prefer to pass around modern `Path` over `str`.

Prefer the modern `except (FileNotFoundError, CalledProcessError) as e:` syntax.

Prefer the modern `.check_call()` interface.

Do we *need* to probe `locals()` ?

A multiprocessing `pool` can burn two cores.

---

I understand that `video` is an open file handle, and this function conforms to an API. But rather than schlepping all the bits through the cpython interpreter, it might be slightly faster to pass the child process a pathname and let ffmpeg worry about the reading.